# Custom attribute product listing page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, product-listing

I have created a custom attribute 'manufacturer' with options like 'Fossil, Tommy Hilfiger, etc'. Now I just need listing for each brand.

For example "https://magento.store.com/fossil.phtml" should return all products under the 'Fossil' manufacturer and likewise. Is there any way to accomplish this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where do You display those Manufacturer Options in Frontend, if You can specify i like to try and get you solution @Radhu.

Comment: Actually i didn't want to display the value of 'Manufacturer' attribute. I just want to display the products of one brand in separate page. For example say the  products of 'fossil'  in "https://magento.store.com/fossil.html" or in "https://magento.store.com/brand?id=22" , and the products of tommy hilfiger in "https://magento.store.com/tommy.html" or  "https://magento.store.com/brand?id=23" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logic to filter products by your custom attribute **manufacturer**.

Below example code filters products with attribute **manufacturer** value Fossil.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', 'Fossil');

foreach ($products as $product) {
    /* Your logic here */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, Cool. But how can we create the separate page for each manufacturer. Like I mentioned in my question "https://magento.store.com/fossil.phtml" for 'Fossil' and likewise.

Comment: Ah I see! I got it wrong. Now, I understand the issue. There is lot of work that is involved in what you want to achieve. Its wise to use a third party extension. If you want to go with a free extension, then I would suggest installing [Attribute Splash Pages](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/extensions/attribute-splash-pages/) extension by Fishpig.  And, there are many more paid extensions available out there too.  Couple of them are https://marketplace.magento.com/swissup-attributepages.html,  https://templates-master.com/magento-brands-and-attributes-pages.html. Good luck!

Comment: thanks @nikin, I have used Attribute splash page plugin

Answer (score 0):

After all researches, I made it. Like I have created a CMS page in CMS > Pages with content

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/brands.phtml"}}
```

So the URL looks like.

```
 https://magento.store.com/brand?q=fossil
```

For listing the products corresponding to brands

```
$brand = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('q');



$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute("brands");
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
     $brand_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId($brand);
     //$brand_label = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($brand_id);
}

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->prepareProductCollection($_productCollection);
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter(array( array( 'attribute' => 'brands', 'eq' => $brand_id ) ))->addStoreFilter();
```

the above logic will find the attribute id first. Then it will add to addAttributeToFilter to find corresponding product collection. Then we can give the style to the listing.